# linux permisos de superusuario en Todas las particiones

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, gnu

Recientemente instale Linux MINT 19.3 Tricia para probarlo, y veo que por defecto, crea archivos y capetas con permisos de superusuario en el sistema. Hasta cierto punto se vuelve moslesto, ya que al intentar eliminar cualquier archivo o carpeta, tengo que autenticarme como ROOT.

Tengo tambien dual boot con windows y en las particiones de este, solo tengo permisos de lectura. he intentado cambiarlos a 777 estando en superusuario pero no funciona.

¿Hay alguna manera de cambiar los permisos a las particiones?

Comment: Eso es por diseño. No es nada sensato dejar al usuario Juan como dueño de los archivos del sistema. Lo que se puede es añádir a Juan a los sudoers, asumiendo las consecuencias. Ya he visto mailing lists donde alguien se queja porque borró un apache la noche anterior al llegar borracho :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para que no necesites siempre auntenticarte como `root` podrías agregar a tu usuario permisos de root en `/etc/sudoers` y darle todos los privilegios, si tu usuario es `juan`.

```
1.nano /etc/sudoers
```

Luego que estas adentro,debajo de la  linea de root añades  el tuyo exactamente igual, es decir asi:

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
juan    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Guardas las modificaciones con  Ctrl+O y Ctrl+X

Comment: Muchas Gracias, estaba pensando en volver a windows por ese  inconveniente xD

Answer (score 0):

si estas tratando de editar o eliminar archivos delicados desde el entorno gráfico en mint el gestor de archivos se llama nemo y para poder realizar esas acciones tienes que darle permiso de administrador, desde el bash le puedes dar permiso de super usuario y eso te permitirá hacer lo que quieras desde el gestor gráfico de archivos (cuidado con esto que puedes romper el so), deberia bastar con escribir lo siguiente:

```
   sudo nemo
```